# Plotting Matrix Operator in Matlab

Tags: sequences-and-series, matrices, functional-analysis, graphing-functions, matlab

How to plot a matrix operator in matlab ? Let us take a matrix, Euler matrix $E^r=(e^{r}_{nk})$ defined by 
\begin{equation}
e^{r}_{nk}=
\begin{cases}
\binom{n}{k}(1-r)^{n-k}r^k &\quad (0\leq k\leq n)\\
0  &\quad (k>n),
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
where $0<r<1$. Now for some particular values of $r$ say $r=\frac{1}{2}$, how do we plot the matrix $E^r$ using MATLAB. Please share MATLAB programming as I am new to MATLAB.

Comment: How would you plot it with a pen?

Comment: This question is probably more relevant to Stack Overflow since it is about the coding aspect of the problem rather than the math aspect.